# app gets build but it is crashing on pressing button the

Tags: java, android

[log cat]Here is my Myactivity
It is a basic app without any transitions or advanced android features
it us based on cow bull game
it contains only one button
some text views
and one plain text

```
package com.example.cowsandbulls;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.*;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int number,c,b;
    char a,w,x,y,z;
    List<Integer> numlist;
    public void generateCbNumber(){
        c=0;
        b=0;
        List list= new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(9);
        List numlist= new ArrayList();
        numlist.add(list.get((int)(Math.random()*9)));
        list.remove(numlist.get(0));
        numlist.add(list.get((int)(Math.random()*9)));
        list.remove(numlist.get(1));
        numlist.add(list.get((int)(Math.random()*9)));
        list.remove(numlist.get(2));
        numlist.add(list.get((int)(Math.random()*9)));
        list.remove(numlist.get(3));
        char w= (char) numlist.get(0);
        char x= (char) numlist.get(0);
        char y= (char) numlist.get(0);
        char z= (char) numlist.get(0);
 
    }
    public void clickFunction(View view)
    { Log.i("INFO","button pressed");
        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        a=0;
        String Text=editText.getText().toString();
        int number=Integer.parseInt(Text);
        if(number>999 && number<10000) {
 
            if(Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(1) || Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(2) || Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(3) || Text.charAt(1) == Text.charAt(2) || Text.charAt(1) == Text.charAt(3) || Text.charAt(2) == Text.charAt(3))
            {‌{Toast.makeText(this,"No repititions",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}
            else if(Text.charAt(0) == a || Text.charAt(1) == a || Text.charAt(2) == a || Text.charAt(3) == a)
            {Toast.makeText(this,"Number should not contain 0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            else if(Text.charAt(0) == w && Text.charAt(1) == x && Text.charAt(2) == y && Text.charAt(3) == z){
                Toast.makeText(this,"4 Bull you win !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                generateCbNumber();
            }
            else {
                if (Text.charAt(0) == w) {
                    b++;
                } else if (Text.charAt(0) == x || Text.charAt(0) == y || Text.charAt(0) == z) {
                    c++;
                }
                if (Text.charAt(1) == x) {
                    b++;
                } else if (Text.charAt(1) == w || Text.charAt(1) == y || Text.charAt(1) == z) {
                    c++;
                }
                if (Text.charAt(2) == y) {
                    b++;
                } else if (Text.charAt(2) == x || Text.charAt(2) == w || Text.charAt(2) == z) {
                    c++;
                }
                if (Text.charAt(3) == z) {
                    b++;
                } else if (Text.charAt(3) == x || Text.charAt(3) == y || Text.charAt(3) == z) {
                    c++;
                }
                String cow = Integer.toString(c);
                String bull = Integer.toString(b);
                Toast.makeText(this, cow + " Cow " + bull + " Bull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 
                generateCbNumber();
            }
        if(number<=100 || number>=10000) {
            if(number==0)
            {Toast.makeText(this, "The Number is"+w+x+y+z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a four digit number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
 
 
        }
 
 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

```
Log cat window
2020-05-14 19:12:59.326 7283-7283/com.example.cowsandbulls I/INFO: button pressed
2020-05-14 19:12:59.332 7283-7283/com.example.cowsandbulls D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-14 19:12:59.334 7283-7283/com.example.cowsandbulls E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cowsandbulls, PID: 7283
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
        at com.example.cowsandbulls.MainActivity.generateCbNumber(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.example.cowsandbulls.MainActivity.clickFunction(MainActivity.java:89)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BCD4"
    android:backgroundTint="#07D0EA"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="169dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="512dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Enter a four digit number"
        android:textColor="#232020"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#E7252729"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="292dp"
        android:background="#03A9F4"
        android:onClick="clickFunction"
        android:text="Check"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="(without repititions not containing zero)"
        android:textColor="#C80B0A0A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey buddy! I know you want to be nice, but please remove that `Please help out` part. At max once is okay. Otherwise, there is a high chance, your question will be removed by moderators.

Comment: Please describe in words, what you intend to do. It is very hard to imagine what is the purpose of your code by looking at the code.

Comment: Please share the exception logs

Comment: is the **Log.i("INFO","button pressed");** appear in logcat ??

Comment: Sorry if it's odd i have done that beacause stackoverflow is showing very less description and I'm not able to post

Comment: Yes Akram Bensalem

Comment: why are you removing items from `list`?

Comment: To avoid repetition of digits

Comment: i shared log cat window details above check it

Comment: Share the `xml` of `activity_main` also. Did you set `android:onClick` in `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: ya i set it to clickFunction Chaitanya chavali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `generateCbNumber` sets the value of `w,x,y,z` randomly. and then you are calling it whenever the user enters a four-digit number. Then I think your code must be

```
public void generateCbNumber(){
    c=0;
    b=0;
    List list= new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(9);
    
    int r;
    List numlist= new ArrayList();

    r=(int)(Math.random()*9)
    numlist.add(list.get(r));
    list.remove(r);

    r=(int)(Math.random()*8)
    numlist.add(list.get(r));
    list.remove(r);

    r=(int)(Math.random()*7)
    numlist.add(list.get(r));
    list.remove(r);

    r=(int)(Math.random()*6)
    numlist.add(list.get(r));
    list.remove(r);
    

    int W=  numlist.get(0);
    int X=  numlist.get(1);
    int Y=  numlist.get(2);
    int Z=  numlist.get(3);

    this.w = '0'+(char)W;
    this.x = '0'+(char)X;
    this.y = '0'+(char)Y;
    this.z = '0'+(char)Z;


}
```

Also, you should call this `generateCbNumber` in `onCreate` to set initial values.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    generateCbNumber();
}
```

**Final Edit(Working and tested):**
I have tested and it is working with this code.

```
    package com.example.cowsandbulls;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int number,c,b;
    char a,w,x,y,z;
    List<Integer> numlist;
    public void generateCbNumber(){
        c=0;
        b=0;
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(9);

        int r;
        List<Integer> numlist= new ArrayList();

        r=(int)(Math.random()*9);
        numlist.add(list.get(r));
        list.remove(r);

        r=(int)(Math.random()*8);
        numlist.add(list.get(r));
        list.remove(r);

        r=(int)(Math.random()*7);
        numlist.add(list.get(r));
        list.remove(r);

        r=(int)(Math.random()*6);
        numlist.add(list.get(r));
        list.remove(r);


        int W=  numlist.get(0);
        int X=  numlist.get(1);
        int Y=  numlist.get(2);
        int Z=  numlist.get(3);

        this.w = (char)W;
        this.w += '0';

        this.x = (char)X;
        this.x += '0';

        this.y = (char)Y;
        this.y += '0';

        this.z = (char)Z;
        this.z += '0';

    }
public void clickFunction(View view)
{ Log.i("INFO","button pressed");
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    a=0;
    String Text=editText.getText().toString();
    int number=Integer.parseInt(Text);
    if(number>999 && number<10000) {

        if (Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(1) || Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(2) || Text.charAt(0) == Text.charAt(3) || Text.charAt(1) == Text.charAt(2) || Text.charAt(1) == Text.charAt(3) || Text.charAt(2) == Text.charAt(3)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No repititions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (Text.charAt(0) == a || Text.charAt(1) == a || Text.charAt(2) == a || Text.charAt(3) == a) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number should not contain 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (Text.charAt(0) == w && Text.charAt(1) == x && Text.charAt(2) == y && Text.charAt(3) == z) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "4 Bull you win !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            generateCbNumber();
        } else {
            if (Text.charAt(0) == w) {
                b++;
            } else if (Text.charAt(0) == x || Text.charAt(0) == y || Text.charAt(0) == z) {
                c++;
            }
            if (Text.charAt(1) == x) {
                b++;
            } else if (Text.charAt(1) == w || Text.charAt(1) == y || Text.charAt(1) == z) {
                c++;
            }
            if (Text.charAt(2) == y) {
                b++;
            } else if (Text.charAt(2) == x || Text.charAt(2) == w || Text.charAt(2) == z) {
                c++;
            }
            if (Text.charAt(3) == z) {
                b++;
            } else if (Text.charAt(3) == x || Text.charAt(3) == y || Text.charAt(3) == z) {
                c++;
            }
            String cow = Integer.toString(c);
            String bull = Integer.toString(b);
            Toast.makeText(this, cow + " Cow " + bull + " Bull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            generateCbNumber();
        }
    }
    if(number<=100 || number>=10000) {
        if(number==0)
        {Toast.makeText(this, "The Number is"+w+x+y+z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a four digit number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }





}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    generateCbNumber();
}
}
```

check this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TFassLpR5QV5vVzoEzdy7B1eh1kH-d49) for images.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213904/discussion-on-answer-by-vss-chaitanya-chavali-app-gets-build-but-it-is-crashing).